# updating an item in a knockout bound list

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a list of questions and each question has a list of answers and I am using knockout to display each question 1 at a time. What I am doing is setting up my model with the full list and then making a currentQuestion property observable and after each question is answered, I increment this to the next question. Problem is that I have to change some data on the question when the user hovers it but cant figure out how to make the answers observable.

I've put together a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gjm0sou9/2/) and what I want to do is change the answer text to 'modified' when the user clicks the answer.

How do I make the AnswerText observable so that when the click handler changes its value this is reflected in the UI.

Any ideas where I am going wrong would be appreciated.

jsfiddle code if below:

```
<div class="top">
  <div data-bind="foreach: currentQuestion().Answers">
    <div data-bind="click: $root.answerClicked">
      <div data-bind="text: AnswerText"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


function MyVM() {
  var self = this;

  this.session = {
    Questions: [
      {
        QuestionText: "Q1",
        Answers: [
          {
            AnswerText: "Q1A1"
          },
          {
            AnswerText: "Q1A2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        QuestionText: "Q2",
        Answers: [
          {
            AnswerText: "Q2A1"
          },
          {
            AnswerText: "Q2A2"
          }
        ]
      }
        ]
  };

  this.currentQuestion = ko.observable();
  this.currentQuestion(self.session.Questions[1]);

  this.answerClicked = function (selectedAnswer, event) {
    alert('hello');
    selectedAnswer.AnswerText = 'modified1';
    selectedAnswer.AnswerText('modified');
  };
}

var model = new MyVM();
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you're binding the UI to a static string. In order to make the UI reflect changes the string must be wrapped in an observable as you stated so it sounds like you were on the right track. All you need to do is use an observable in each answer object.

```
    Answers: [
      {
        AnswerText: ko.observable("Q2A1")
      },
      {
        AnswerText: ko.observable("Q2A2")
      }
    ]
```

Then in the click function you'll want to get rid of the first assignment operator where it would be replacing the observable and use only the second line where a value is assigned to the observable instead.

```
  this.answerClicked = function (selectedAnswer, event) {
    alert('hello');
    //selectedAnswer.AnswerText = 'modified1';
    selectedAnswer.AnswerText('modified');
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and that sounds sensible, my only problem is that in the real app (I cut it down for the sake of simplicity) the object that is assigned to this.session actually comes back from an Ajax call so I'd need to somehow have to traverse the Answers in all the questions and make them observable. Would that just be a case of replacing each answer.AnswerText = ko.observable(answer.AnswerText )

Comment: I tried an update of the jsfiddle but have obviously got something  wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/gjm0sou9/3/

Comment: ok, small typo fixed and its now working a treat, thanks for your input. 

Final Result: http://jsfiddle.net/gjm0sou9/4/

Comment: That certainly works. You might also try looking into the Mapping plugin if your data becomes too complicated to map by hand. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Comment: Thanks, the plugin looks good but does bloat the payload a bit and also might be a bit of overkill in my situation making all properties and lists observable. I've implemented the loops and that works well but I'm a bit confused as to why I was unable to do it on the fly in the click handler by making it observable if its not already observable. See this version of the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gjm0sou9/6/ that doesnt work but shows what I mean